# How to use F1 score in tensor2tensor

Tags: tensor2tensor

I want to add F1 score on my multiclass classification problem. I did not find F1 in the build-in metrics list. Is F1 somewhere in tensor2tensor or I have to overwrite eval_metrics() and use my code or take it from TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it from scikit learn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
```

Then you can do

```
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_classes)
print(f1)
```

Comment: that is not a systematic solution, there should be some more elegant way to add "user" metrics in this specific framework